# R: find every sequence of consecutive (neg,neg,neg) numbers in timeseries

Tags: r, algorithm, sequence

I can't find a way out on this problem: for each column of my dataframe I need to find, and put on a new dataframe, all the negative triplets (sequences of consecutive negative values) and the single value (either positive or negative) that chronologically follows the triplet. For instance, in column TSL I need to keep the values -4, -1, -3, 1 and the associated dates.
I am not very senior at R, so I spent a considerable amount of time trying to figure out different strategies: for loop with nested ifs, dplyr with quantmod for timeseries and lag. So far I have been unsuccessful. Anyone that could point me in the right direction? Thank you

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th>TSL</th>
<th>FAS</th>
<th>GMV</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>2019-01-03</th>
<th>-3</th>
<th>-1</th>
<th>-4</th>
<tr>
<th>2019-01-04</th>
<th>5</th>
<th>3</th>
<th>3</th>
</tr><tr>
<th>2019-01-07</th>
<th>5</th>
<th>2</th>
<th>3</th>
</tr><tr>
<th>2019-01-08</th>
<th>0</th>
<th>0</th>
<th>1</th>
</tr><tr>
<th>2019-01-09</th>
<th>0</th>
<th>4</th>
<th>1</th>
</tr><tr>
<th>2019-01-10</th>
<th>1</th>
<th>-0</th>
<th>-1</th>
</tr><tr>
<th>2019-01-11</th>
<th>0</th>
<th>1</th>
<th>7</th>
</tr><tr>
<th>2019-01-14</th>
<th>-3</th>
<th>1</th>
<th>1</th>
</tr><tr>
<th>2019-01-15</th>
<th>2</th>
<th>-1</th>
<th>-0</th>
</tr><tr>
<th>2019-01-16</th>
<th>0</th>
<th>-6</th>
<th>0</th>
</tr><tr>
<th>2019-01-17</th>
<th>0</th>
<th>0</th>
<th>1</th>
</tr><tr>
<th>2019-01-18</th>
<th>-4</th>
<th>2</th>
<th>0</th>
</tr><tr>
<th>2019-01-22</th>
<th>-1</th>
<th>-0</th>
<th>-1</th>
</tr><tr>
<th>2019-01-23</th>
<th>-3</th>
<th>-1</th>
<th>-1</th>
</tr><tr>
<th>2019-01-24</th>
<th>1</th>
<th>3</th>
<th>1</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

---

Data

```r
structure(list(Date = structure(c(17899, 17900, 17903, 17904, 17905, 17906, 17907, 17910, 17911, 17912, 17913, 17914, 17918, 17919, 17920), class = "Date"), TSL = c(-3L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, -3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, -4L, -1L, -3L, 1L), FAS = c(-1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 1L, -1L, -6L, 0L, 2L, 0L, -1L, 3L), GMV = c(-4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 7L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, -1L, -1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Comment: Can you please paste your data in a way that we can use without having to parse HTML? Often, the output from `dput(x)` is great.

Comment: (I suggested an edit that includes that sample data in an unambiguous format. If you don't like that, my apologies, feel free to rollback or delete it.)

Comment: Thank you very much r2evans and @Jordan for your suggestions, I took some time to study both and come up with a solution that exactly fits my needs. Probably not higly efficient (but it catches all the triplets), here it is anyway: 
get_sets <- function(x, dates) {
sx <- sign(x)
rlesx <- rle(sx) 
w <- which (rlesx$lengths >= 3 & rlesx$values == -1)
ind <- c()
for (i in w){
a <- sum((rlesx$lengths[1:(i-1)]),1)
b <- (a + 3)
c <- seq.int((a), b)
ind <- append (ind,c)
}
list(
    dates = dates[ind],
    set = x[ind]
  )
}

lapply(df2[, 2:4], get_sets, dates = df2$Date)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```r
(starts <- lapply(dat[,-1], function(z) zoo::rollapply(z, 4, FUN = function(y) length(y) == 4L && all(y[1:3] < 0) && y[4] > 0, partial = TRUE, align = "left")))
# $TSL
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# $FAS
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# $GMV
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
(use <- lapply(starts, function(z) zoo::rollapply(z, 4, FUN = any, align = "right", partial = TRUE)))
# $TSL
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# $FAS
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# $GMV
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
lapply(use, function(ind) dat[ind,])
# $TSL
#          Date TSL FAS GMV
# 12 2019-01-18  -4   2   0
# 13 2019-01-22  -1   0  -1
# 14 2019-01-23  -3  -1  -1
# 15 2019-01-24   1   3   1
# $FAS
# [1] Date TSL  FAS  GMV 
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
# $GMV
# [1] Date TSL  FAS  GMV 
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

The way my code above works:

- the first `zoo::rollapply` does a rolling window operation, looking at 4 at a time: positions 1-4, then 2-5, then 3-6, then 4-7, etc, in the vector it is passed. In the first column, it finally sees `-4, -1, -3` and then `1`, and the logic in the internal anon-function passes and returns a single `TRUE` for that position. This produces the `starts` listed above, which indicates the *first* row for a sequence of 3-neg and 1-pos.
- the second `zoo::rollapply` extends that the length needed. (It might be possible to combine those into one call.)
- I wrap each of those into `lapply` so that the calculation is done on each of the columns; `lapply(dat[,-1], ...)` is doing it for all but the first (`Date`) columns.
- Finally, the last `lapply` just subsets the data into a list of three frames, each containing the sequences.

Answer (score 0):

All within base R

This uses similar logic to base::rle.  We can get the `sign()` of the value to determine if it is positive (`1`) or negative `-1` (`sign()` recodes `0` as `0`).  We can then check to see how many repeated values we have by shifting the numbers up and down which are still equal.

From there we can get the FIRST triplet (enhancements would need to be made for multiple matches) and create a suitable vector of positions to extract from our dates and the 4 numbers.

I wasn't quite sure what you wanted the final data.frame to look like so I haven't included that.

```r
# Recreating data frame
dx <- c(17899,17900, 17903, 17904, 17905, 17906, 17907, 17910, 17911, 17912,
        17913, 17914, 17918, 17919, 17920)

df <- data.frame(
  Date = as.Date(dx, origin = "1970-01-01"),
  TSL = c(-3L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, -3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, -4L, -1L, -3L, 1L),
  FAS = c(-1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 1L, -1L, -6L, 0L, 2L, 0L, -1L, 3L),
  GMV = c(-4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 7L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, -1L, -1L, 1L)
)


df2 <- data.frame(
  Date = as.Date(dx, origin = "1970-01-01"),
  TSL = c(-3L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, -3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, -4L, -1L, -3L, 1L),
  FAS = c(-1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -6L, 0L, -2L, 0L, -1L, 3L),
  GMV = c(-4L, -3L, -3L, 1L, 1L, -1L, -7L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, -1L, -1L, 1L)
)

x <- df2[[3]]

# adapted from base::rle
get_sets <- function(x, dates) {
  n <- length(x)
  sx <- sign(x)
  y <- sx[-1L] != sx[-n]
  i <- c(which(y | is.na(y)), n)
  res <- diff(c(0L, i))
  # w is where the FIRST triplet is found
  w <- which(res >= 3 & sx[1] == -1)[1]
  
  # Check if any are found
  if (anyNA(w)) {
    return(list(dates = NULL, set = NULL))
  }
  
  ind <- sum(res[seq.int(0, w - 1L)]) + 1
  inds <- seq.int(ind, ind + 3)
  list(
    dates = dates[inds],
    set = x[inds]
  )
}

# Applying to each column
lapply(df[, 2:4], get_sets, dates = df$Date)
#> $TSL
#> $TSL$dates
#> [1] "2019-01-18" "2019-01-22" "2019-01-23" "2019-01-24"
#> 
#> $TSL$set
#> [1] -4 -1 -3  1
#> 
#> 
#> $FAS
#> $FAS$dates
#> NULL
#> 
#> $FAS$set
#> NULL
#> 
#> 
#> $GMV
#> $GMV$dates
#> [1] "2019-01-04" "2019-01-07" "2019-01-08" "2019-01-09"
#> 
#> $GMV$set
#> [1] 3 3 1 1
lapply(df2[, 2:4], get_sets, dates = df2$Date)
#> $TSL
#> $TSL$dates
#> [1] "2019-01-18" "2019-01-22" "2019-01-23" "2019-01-24"
#> 
#> $TSL$set
#> [1] -4 -1 -3  1
#> 
#> 
#> $FAS
#> $FAS$dates
#> [1] "2019-01-14" "2019-01-15" "2019-01-16" "2019-01-17"
#> 
#> $FAS$set
#> [1] -1 -1 -6  0
#> 
#> 
#> $GMV
#> $GMV$dates
#> [1] "2019-01-03" "2019-01-04" "2019-01-07" "2019-01-08"
#> 
#> $GMV$set
#> [1] -4 -3 -3  1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>